# C++ and Python version of the same algorithm giving different result

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, python-3.x, triangle-count

The following code is an algorithm to determine the amount of integer triangles, with their biggest side being smaller or equal to MAX, that have an integer median. The Python version works but is too slow for bigger N, while the C++ version is a lot faster but doesn't give the right result.

When MAX is 10, C++ and Python both return 3.

When MAX is 100, Python returns 835 and C++ returns 836.

When MAX is 200, Python returns 4088 and C++ returns 4102.

When MAX is 500, Python returns 32251 and C++ returns 32296.

When MAX is 1000, Python returns 149869 and C++ returns 150002.

Here's the C++ version:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>

const int MAX = 1000;

int main()
{
    long long int x = 0;
    for (int b = MAX; b > 4; b--)
    {
        printf("%lld\n", b);
        for (int a = b; a > 4; a -= 2){
            for (int c = floor(b/2); c < floor(MAX/2); c+=1)
            {
                if (a+b > 2*c){
                    int d = 2*(pow(a,2)+pow(b,2)-2*pow(c,2));
                    if (sqrt(d)/2==floor(sqrt(d)/2))
                        x+=1;
                }
            }
            }
    }
    printf("Done: ");       
    printf("%lld\n", x);
}
```

Here's the original Python version:

```
import math

def sumofSquares(n):
    f = 0
    for b in range(n,4,-1):
        print(b)
        for a in range(b,4,-2):
            for C in range(math.ceil(b/2),n//2+1):
                if a+b>2*C:
                    D = 2*(a**2+b**2-2*C**2)
                    if (math.sqrt(D)/2).is_integer():
                        f += 1
    return f

a = int(input())
print(sumofSquares(a))
print('Done')
```

I'm not too familiar with C++ so I have no idea what could be happening that's causing this (maybe an overflow error?).

Of course, any optimizations for the algorithm are more than welcome!

Comment: Well for one, the C++ version is using `floor` while python is using `ceil`. Also the C++ version is not dividing by 2 `if (sqrt(d)==floor(sqrt(d)))` while the python one is `if (math.sqrt(2*D)/2).is_integer():`

Comment: The python version gives me `4` for an input of `10`.

Comment: They both have the multiply by 2 (just in different places) but only the Python one has a divide by 2 after the square root.

Comment: @BradBudlong, yup just saw that, but notice that when the python version multiplies by 2, it also divides by 2

Comment: I can replicate your C++ results, but not your python results.

Comment: pypy3 runs this _much_ faster than cpython. http://pypy.org/download.html

Comment: What prevents you from putting in some `print`s in both versions and check whey do they differ?

Comment: @huu, I have copied and pasted the code just to be sure, I don't know why it's returning a different value for you.


Just in case, I've edited the codes posted and made sure both variables are multiplied and divided in the same way.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy I'm familiar with PyPy but C++ is still faster.

Comment: @NicolásSiplis, not if you include the time you've spent debugging this :)

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Unfortunately, considering how long it's going to take to calculate for MAX = 100000... it is faster D:

Comment: @NicolásSiplis, how much faster do you guess C++ will be?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Considering this is gonna take 10^10/2 calculations (approx.), even if it were 1% faster it'd make a considerable difference.

Comment: @NicolásSiplis, Indeed. You probably need to port this to run on a GPU or an ASIC

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Considering I'm on my first year of college... I'll wait, hehe.

Would running it on a GPU significantly increase speed? I have no clue on the exact differences TBH.

Comment: @NicolásSiplis, Aside: For 10000, the difference between C++ and Python on my computer was between 1 and 2 percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the range for your `c` (`C` in python) variables do not match. To make them equivalent to your existing C++ range, you can change your python loop to:

```
for C in range(int(math.floor(b/2)), int(math.floor(n/2))):
    ...
```

To make them equivalent to your existing python range, you can change your C++ loop to:

```
for (int c = ceil(b/2.0); c < MAX/2 + 1; c++) {
    ...
}
```

Depending on which loop is originally correct, this will make the results match.

Comment: I just tried changing the loop in C++ but now the result is even more off. It returns 150632 when MAX is 1000!

Comment: What *should* be the correct answer? All my answer shows you is that your algorithms give different results because they're constructed differently.

Comment: The correct answer would be 149869, the one outputted by Python.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion the algorithm you posted does not give that answer, especially when I transcribe the python algorithm to C++ I get the same result as in python. For reference, I get `150632` as well when I use your posted python algorithm, even in C++.

Comment: I honestly don't know what to tell you. Just in case, I've copied and pasted the Python code in my original post and the output is 149869. C++, on the other hand, does output 150632.

Comment: I've got it, it's because you're using Python 3 and I'm using Python 2. I'll edit my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Whew, thought I was going crazy for a moment. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my answer, the C++ code should give you the same answers as your original python algorithm.

Comment: It does! I don't get it though, the only difference is the 2.0 instead of a 2 (removing the int function doesn't affect the answer). So... why in the world is there any difference betwen the two?

Comment: When you do `b/2`, this will automatically truncate the decimal, effectively applying a floor function for positive values of `b`. When you take the `ceil` of a `floor`, that's equivalent to taking a `floor`. To get the correct `ceil`, you have to trick it into *not* truncating the decimals since the decimals are critical to your `ceil` call. You can do this by dividing by a floating point number instead of integral value, hence the `2.0`.

Comment: Good to know! One thing I hate is the different ways in which each language deals with floats... I'll be sure to remember this next time, thanks!

Comment: In integer division, `(b+1)/2` should give the same result as `ceil(b/2.0)`. I'd avoid `pow(a,2)` etc for integer `a`, just use `a*a`. In python, `a**2` stays integer.

Answer (score -1):

It seams some troubles could be here:

```
(sqrt(d)==floor(sqrt(d)))
```